# Most efficient way to calculate count of consecutive buildings that are shorter than current buildings

Tags: c++, algorithm

In below code snippet The program calculates the count of consecutive buildings that are shorter than the current building. It starts with an initial count of 0 and adds 1 to the count for each building that is shorter than the current building. When it encounters a building that is taller or equal, it adds the current count to the total count and resets the count to 0.
but this solution's time complexity is o (n2) and doesn't look more effective if no. of building is more . How to improve this solution ? Any suggested pointer will be helpful for me.

Note: Array of building size >=6 and <=80000 and height of building can be 1 to 100000000

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";
    
    int N;

int count = 0;
int total_count = 0;

int output ;

int H [] = {5,3,4,2,6,1};

int size = sizeof(H) / sizeof(H[0]);


for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++)
    {
     for (int j = i+1 ; j < size ; j++) 
     {
         
         if (H[i] > H[j])
         {
             
             count ++;
             
             std::cout<<"count value  = " << count << H[i] << std::endl;
             
            }
         
         else
         {
        
             
             total_count = total_count + count ;
             
             count = 0;
             break;
         }
         
         
     }
        
        
    } 
    //  Write the code
     total_count = total_count + count ;
    
         
     output = total_count;
     cout << "output = "<<output << endl;   //  Output right answer
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should read about Kadane algorithm

Comment: This can be done in one pass while maintaining a `std::map<int, int>` or similar - a map of height to the most recently seen index of the building of that height. Ends up being `O(n log n)` I think. Implementation is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: *"this solution's time complexity is o (n2)"* -- what you described is O(n). Perhaps you meant *"The program calculates, **for each building,** the count of consecutive buildings that are shorter than the current building"* (with a similar addition to your description of the algorithm)?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  Kadane's algorithm is used to find the maximum subarray sum in an array of numbers, and it is not directly applicable to the problem described here.

Comment: @JaMiT   solution which I have provided is o (n2) and it needs to be optimized . It is expected that algorithm should solve this problem within 2 secs.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik    How map is going to calculate sum of  less than array element's count here . Could you elaborate here as still you need to lopp through and count the numbers.

Comment: After each step, the map would contain heights and indexes of all the buildings for which you haven't yet seen a taller building. When you see `H[i]` on step `i`, this closes off all the runs for shorter buildings; the length of each such run is the difference between the two indexes. So you remove these shorter heights from the map, adjust total count accordingly, and add `{H[i], i}` to the map as a start of a new run.

Comment: @user2997518 *"solution which I have provided is o (n2)"* -- Do you mean your code? Because I referred to your text. Starting a count at 0 is O(1). Doing fixed-time operations (either adding 1 to one count or adding two counts and resetting one of them to 0) for each building is O(n). These combine to be O(n). Your text describes an O(n) solution (because it does not account for the current building changing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an O(n) method

The main idea is that we are not interested to count the numbers of lower elements of each sample, but the total sum of them.

This allows another approach. For each new element, we count the number of elements which are higher than the current one, which are memorized in a stack.

Therefore, for each new element, we suppress the elements which are lower or equal, and then add the size of the stack to the total count.
The new  element is then added to the stack.

Ths complexity is O(n) because each element is added or removed only once to/from the stack.

The following code compares the result of the new approach with the brute-force O(n^2) one.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>

//  Brute-force (OP) method

int count_bf (const std::vector<int>& H) {
    int size = H.size();
    int total_count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1 ; j < size ; j++) {
            if (H[i] > H[j]){
                total_count ++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    } 
    return total_count;
}

// Fast method

int count_fast (const std::vector<int>& H) {
    int size = H.size();
    int total_count = 0;
    std::stack<int> lifo;
    for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++) {
        while (!lifo.empty() && (lifo.top() <= H[i])) {
            lifo.pop();
        }
        total_count += lifo.size();
        lifo.push(H[i]);
    } 
    return total_count;
}

int main() {    
    std::vector<int> H = {5, 3, 4, 2, 6, 1, 13, 15, 17, 14, 13};

    int total_count = count_bf(H);
    std::cout << "output brute-force method = "<< total_count << std::endl;
    total_count = count_fast(H);
    std::cout << "output fast method = "<< total_count << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```